# Match and extract value from string pattern and replace with value corresponds to array key

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have 2 array both contains person and fruits name. Both array are dynamically generated.

```
$persons = array(0 =>'John', 1 => 'Alan', 2 => 'Ninja');

$fruits = array(0 =>'apple', 1 => 'mango', 2 => 'banana', 3 => 'kiwi');
```

And a string on which I want to perform replacement on the basis of the key provided with the pattern.

```
$str = "[person1] eats [fruit1]";
$str2 = "These [fruit2] belongs to [person3] and his friends";
```

I want my output to be like

```
$str = "John eats apple";
$str2 = "These mango belongs to Ninja and his friends";
```

I want to search for pattern and get value of `*` from pattern `[person*]` and `[fruit*]` where `*` is dynamically generated string.

**Edit 1**

I Created a function

```
function replaceable_string($str, $elements, $pattern, $match="*"){
   foreach($elements as $index => $element){
     $index++;
     $new_pattern = str_replace($match, $index, $pattern);
     $str = str_replace($new_pattern, $element, $str);
   }
  return $str;
}
```

and Passed value like this

```
$str = replaceable_string($str, $persons, '[person*]');
$str = replaceable_string($str, $fruits, '[fruit*]');
echo $str;
```

I don't know how much efficient this is.

Or is there any other best possible way to achieve this?

Comment: have you considered a "proper" templateing system

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it. Not sure about more efficient or not.

```
        $persons = array(0 =>'John', 1 => 'Alan', 2 => 'Ninja');

        $fruits = array(0 =>'apple', 1 => 'mango', 2 => 'banana', 3 => 'kiwi');

        $str = "[person1] eats [fruit1]";
        $str2 = "These [fruit2] belongs to [person3] and his friends";

        function replaceFromArr($str) {      
            global $persons, $fruits;
            $matches = [];
            preg_match_all("/\[([^\]]*)\]/", $str, $matches);
                //var_dump($matches[1]);

                foreach($matches[1] as $matched) {
                    // echo "$matched <br>";
                    $substr = substr($matched,0,6);
                    if($substr == "person") {
                        // extract index and fetch from persons array 
                        $index = substr($matched,6);
                        $replace = $persons[$index-1];

                        $str = str_replace("[$matched]",$replace,$str);                    
                    }
                    else {
                        // extract index and fetch from fruits array 
                        $index = substr($matched,5);
                        $replace = $fruits[$index-1];

                        $str = str_replace("[$matched]",$replace,$str);                   

                    }
                }                
            return $str;
        }


        $newStr = replaceFromArr($str);
        echo "--- $newStr ---<br>";

        $newStr = replaceFromArr($str2);
        echo "--- $newStr ---<br>";
```